# Queries executing very slowly

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, cloud

I have an sql... It's a "SELECT". I can't show it, but it has 5 unions and a lot of joins (inner and left). I have also created all the necessary indexes. On the local machine it takes less then a second (~ 0.5 s) to get the results. But on the server it executes very-very long time.
Databases on the local machine and on the server are identical. I've recently dumped the server database and restore it on the local machine.
About 35 minutes ago I launched an "EXPLAIN" of this sql and it is still running. Also I see "Copying to tmp table" label for that explain in the process list.
All the tables are optimized.
I tested with MyISAM and InnoDB engines.
The server load average is less than 1, MySQL is not under load too.

It might be important - server on a cloud service. I have no access to the cloud statistics - just use the server.

What can you suggest me?

Comment: Explain is taking 35 minutes? Google MySql Explain slow.

Comment: If an explain is taking 35 minutes, then you have major problems with the server or the connection to the server.

Comment: Can you show the query and change the tablenames/fields etc?

Comment: Maybe server is performing another heavy action?

Comment: I launch queries from the server. i don't connect to the mysql using remote connection. I connect via SSH to the server and then connect to the mysql server on that machine.

Comment: CPU is idle. Server has 16G RAM but only 500M-1G is free. The rest memory distributed mostly between mysql (~3500M) and php (10 process of php-fpm allocate 1200M-1300M of virtual memory each).

Comment: Another intresting thing. Just now I've launched explain queries for every 5 parts (as I said before the query is a union of the 5 subqueries) of the query and it taken a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.
As I said before (in the comments) I did EXPLAINs for every subqueries and noticed some differences with the same EXPLAINs on the local machine (for 2 of 5 subqueries).
It solved by creating additional indexes.
Different machines - different results. I expected that it would be some differences, but I could not even did the EXPLAIN. That's a strange. Helped only the partial EXPALINs.

Thanks for all.